# Qt Signal/Slot Issue

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slots

I can't figure out what's going wrong here.
I want to pass a value from a class to another.
Here's the code:

**mainwindow.h**

```
public slots:
    void printNumbers(int);
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::printNumbers(int a)
{
    qDebug() << a;
}
```

**myudp.h**

```
signals:
    inline void sendBuff(int);
```

**myudp.cpp**

```
        [***]
        MainWindow *widget = new MainWindow();
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
        const bool connected = connect(this , SIGNAL(sendBuff(int)), widget ,SLOT(printNumbers(int)));
        qDebug() << "Connection established?" << connected;
        [***]

    void MyUDP::readyRead()
    {
        // when data comes in
        emit sendBuff(13);

        [***]
    }

    inline void MyUDP::sendBuff(int a)
    {
        qDebug() << "sending " << a ;
    }
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window;
    MainWindow *widget = new MainWindow();
    window.setCentralWidget(widget);
    window.resize(900, 600);
    window.show();
    MyUDP *client = new MyUDP();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I used "inline" because of an error: duplicate MyUDP::sendBuff(int a).

I don't know if it can be an issue.

when I execute the "**emit sendBuff(12)**" I only receive "**sending 12**", I didn't catch the **printNumbers()**'s output even if the variable "**connected**" is true.

Comment: Did you check signal is emitted ?  you need to debug `MyUDP::readyRead()` and make sure you socket is working and the `readyread()` is fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the inline declaration of the slot, and if your class needs an internal use for **sendBuff** then declare a new method for that...

```
signals:
    void sendBuffSignal(int);
```

and in the cpp

```
void MyUDP::sendBuff(int a)
{
    qDebug() << "sending " << a ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mate.
I figure out to remove the entire sendBuff declaration and it works.
But If I remove only the inline declaration it returns a duplicate declaration error.
Just to know, do you have any ideas for this issue?